# Explain this regular expression do?

Tags: regex

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:[;][A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})*$|^$
```

Ok, so the first part before `(?:[;]` is understandable

However what starts from `(?:[` is something that confuses me,

Could you explain a that regular expression?

Comment: what language are you referring to ?

Comment: `(?:test)` mean *not capturing group*. Is similar to `(test)` but this last capture in a group result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:ABC)` - Creates a non-capturing group:

> Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex
>   operators, but do not capture anything and do not create
>   backreferences.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

And `[...]` is just a character class that matches the one of the symbols within it.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

The entire regex itself seems to be validating an email address, but in a rather inefficient and complicated manner.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to match one or more email addresses separated by semi-colons (such as for validating the *To:* field of an email.)